# Does the noun cathy have another meaning other than a female name?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, synonyms

I read this book and I saw this:

> About the author: Penn Brooks is a former cathy with 12 years of parochial experience under his belt. He currently lives in New England, where he writes, draws and avoids wearing plaid ties.
> [source](https://archive.bookfrom.net/penn-brooks/page,3,534676-a_diary_of_a_private_school_kid.html)

I, suspecting it could be 'catholic', searched and searched. All that I could get were names explanations.

Comment: I've never encountered that. But the collocation with _parochial_ makes it clear that your guess is right.

Comment: My guess would be it is a term for a teacher in a parochial Catholic school.

Comment: I've never heard the term "cathy" to mean anything. Have you read the book? Is it a jargon term introduced in the book?

Comment: I finished the book the day before yesterday. It's a children's book. This is really about the author, and I'm not sure whether it's a jargon.

Comment: [just jargon, not a jargon]. I have answered the question and you seem not to have seen it. Unless you (anyone here) are familiar with the US term, preppy, you probably won't get this one.

Comment: Why don't you acknowledge my contribution? I seem to be the only one with direct experience of this via the word preppy. It is so frustrating.

Comment: @Lambie I've upvoted because the answer makes sense not because you said you used to attend a Catholic school in the US. I attended a Roman Catholic school run by nuns in the UK and I've never ever heard anyone refer to themselves as a cathy. As far as I can make out, this is a made-up term. There are no sources which support your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I most certainly did not attend a Catholic school and did not say that. I said I attended a prep school, and was, therefore, a preppy. Preppy is not used in the UK, *so I would not have expected*  you to make this connection as I did.  I got it by associating preppy with cathy.  There is nothing else it could be.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the `a cathy here` as being you.

Comment: No, worries. No, I went to a ladeedah Episcopal girls' school.  Episcopal being  AmE Church of England, by the way. And boy, did I ever loathe it. Two teachers were nice, the rest sucked and the boarding bit, let's not talk about that. :)

Answer (score 2):

a cathy here:

A former student at a Catholic high school.

It could be a nickname for people who went to a Catholic high school. That is typical in Am. English. High schools or the type of high school are given nicknames. **For example: A preppy**. Someone who went to a prep school (college preparatory). It means he is a former student at a [name] Catholic high school.

- A preppy
- A cathy

Comment: Thank you upvoter. Whew. :)

Answer (score -1):

For the specific example you chose, "Cathy" means the same thing as "catholic"

> Penn Brooks is a former **catholic** with 12 years of parochial experience under his belt.

Some Americans believe that people who all have the same first name also have the same personality.

Phrases like, "she such a Kathy," are used as an insult.

The following, does ***NOT*** use the word "Kathy" as a pejorative:

> About the Author: Penn Brooks is a former cathy with 12 years of parochial experience under his belt.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that he would mention his former religious identification in a kids comedy book about life at a private school.  These "author biographies" are usually light hearted.  Talking about losing his religion is the opposite!

Comment: In these cases, embarrassment seems to prime and everyone just jumps ship. I know, this has happened to me. No worries.